# Does firmware depend on OS and architecture?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, kernel, firmware

I learned that  firmware of a device runs in the device. 
So does firmware of a device not depends on the computer architecture and the OS kernel? (I know that a driver of a device depends on arch and OS kernel.)

For exmaple, my internal wireless adapter's firmware is the file:

```
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
```

Is it  specific to my architecture (amd64) and OS kernel(Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 4.0)?

I installed Linux kernel 4.0 created for Vivid on Trusty, and I need to know if I need to update my firmware. If firmware depends on OS kernel, then I will need to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, not at all.
Firmware is what's on the device, so it has nothing to do with our OS nor the computer at all.
It's like, your mp3 player or your modem has it's own firmware, but it works with ANY OS with proper drivers installed.

Comment: Thanks (1) So do you mean a firmware file same as `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode` is also used by Windows, If I also have Windows installed on the same computer as Ubuntu? (2) why is the wireless firmware installed as `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode`, instead of in the wireless adapter?

Comment: read this guide - [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Firmware)

Comment: @Tim, It is not _on_ the wireless device so that it can be easily updated.